# Getting duplicates in kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing a Java client for Kafka consumer.I commit every messages asynchronously before processing it.Still I am receiving many duplicate messages during rebalance.

Can anyone explain the reason and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Consumer does not provide exactly-once processing guarantees, even if you commit all messages **synchronously**.

The problem is, that when you did finish processing a message successfully and want to commit it, the rebalance can happen right before the commit. Thus, your commit is not done and the already processed message will be reprocessed.

Because you use **asynchronous** commits, the number of duplicates increases, as committing does not happen immediately for each single message. Hence, you can have many messages "in-flight" that are finished processing but not committed yet. On rebalance, all "in-flight" message will be re-processed.

So committing **synchronously** will reduce the number of duplicates. However, duplicates cannot be avoided completely, because there is no exactly-once delivery guarantee in Kafka.

Exactly-once delivery is on the roadmap for future release of Kafka though: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging

Comment: I get your point, but here I am committing message asynchronously before processing.In that case, there should not be any duplicates.

Comment: Because of asynchronously committing, the commit might still happen after processing was finished -- and this, if a commit fails, there are still duplicates. You would need to use synchronous commits (or use a commit callback and only process those messages, that got committed already).

Comment: Btw: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging